# How to solve the error of "ERROR: No build artifacts found" after the following build successful msg?

Tags: android, gradle, jitpack

It happened with the following log when I tried to deploy the library through Jitpack.
Anyone who knows the cause of the problem?

- on project level [build.gradle](https://github.com/libliboom/lbzip/blob/master/build.gradle)
- on app level [build.gradle](https://github.com/libliboom/lbzip/blob/master/app/build.gradle)

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 482ms
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
Build tool exit code: 0
Looking for artifacts...
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Looking for pom.xml in build directory and ~/.m2
2019-10-04T08:31:16.46490349Z
Exit code: 0

ERROR: No build artifacts found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve Jitpack "ERROR: No build artifacts found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68511986/how-to-solve-jitpack-error-no-build-artifacts-found)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found why it happened and solved it. I declare it as an application, not library.
 That's why jitpack couldn't find the build artifacts.
I left how I changed it with this [solution](https://github.com/libliboom/lbzip/commit/f2a8cd6edcb941df6af16f846088a3606efdc7fa).

I hope someone can get help from this troubleshooting.

Comment: No proper explanation

Comment: Solution link is not available

Answer (score 0):

Actually I took lots of hours to find this issue. But I found this, my issue was I added **maven** library into my application **build.gradle** but this was wrong you have to put all maven library into your library module **build.gradle**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think OP forgot provide the solution. Here are the steps:

1. In the library build.gradle add:

`apply plugin: 'maven-publish'`

2. In the same build.gradle add this at the bottom:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = '{your_package_name}'
            artifactId = '{your library name}'
            version = '{your.library.version}'
        }
    }
}
```